# How to Manage dependencies in Maven Muti Project across Multiple Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, circular-dependency, maven-bom

I'm having a situation with maven

```
── bom-porject
    ├── pom.xml
```

This is bom proejct is just used to dependency management for external maven dependecy.

This project just publishes a pom file to maven repo

This bom is imported to different projects developed  via `<dependency Management>`

Then I have another a project

```
── project-libs-root
   ├── module-lib-database
   │   └── pom.xml <--- Module lib database POM 
   ├── module-lib-conversions
   │   └── pom.xml <--- Module lib conversion POM
   └── pom.xml     <--- project-libs-root
```

This is some common libraries used by all appliaction that I'm developing .

In `project-libs-root pom.xml`  import `bom-porject pom.xml` using

```
<dependencyManagement>
```

I did this to get access to dependecies defined in bom-project

Then I have another maven project

```
── application-root
   ├── module-app-db
   │   └── pom.xml <--- Module apllication database POM
   ├── module-app-domain
   │   └── pom.xml <--- Module application domain POM
   ├── module-app
   │   └── pom.xml <--- Module application POM (this is a deployment)
   └── pom.xml     <--- application-root
```

This is an application This  `application-root pom.xml` importing
   `project-libs-root pom.xml` via `<dependencyManagement>.`

By doing this I got access to `bom-porject pom.xml` and dependencies
   defined in it

The confusing part around internal modules and manging it's dependecy in project using it For example

Suppose if i need to use artifact `module-lib-database` from `project-libs-root` in `module-app-db` artifact of `application-root` ,
Where should i mention dependency for `module-lib-database`

Currently i'm explicity calling it inside `<dependecies>` tag of `module-app-db pom.xml`

Is there any way I can define it in `project-libs-root` and brought it down to application via `<dependencyMangement>` tag

Comment: why dont you want to use the conventional way, and to declare all your dependencies in your parent-pom, under <dependenciesManagement>. then, each sub-module, which is "under" that parent-pom, can use in its <dependencies> section the dep's that it needs (without the version which is in control of the parent pom). makes sense?

Comment: @OhadR yes that make sense but see I'm using parent pom to manage  only 3rd party dependency. which won't be changing frequently also it will be similar across all my projects. so i'm not willing to give version management to sub projects/domains/module. so are you suggesting to declare all external and internal dependency in parent pom ???

Comment: you can have parent pom with the internal dependencies. this parent pom will have another parent pom, with the 3rd party dep's...

Comment: I second @OhadR and have structure like `parent-project` with all `dependency` and `plugin` configuration. Then `lib-parent` and `application-parent` extends the pom of `parent-project`.

Comment: @RishikeshDarandale currently 'lib-parent' is extending  'parent-project'. if my 'application-parent' needs to used modules developed in 'lib-parent' how can brought in those dependency to  'application-parent' by only using 'lib-parent' pom ??

Comment: @edwin, how about adding another child project `lib-bom` under `lib-parent` ? Use `lib-bom` import in  `application-parent`. `lib-bom` will have declaration to all your `lib modules` with version same to `lib-parent`. Thus in `application-parent` pom you will have two imports `parent-project-bom` and `lib-project-bom`. Finally add your required dependencies in respective modules of `application-parent`.

Comment: @edwin, does my answer helped you to solve your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, this is how I would have tried to setup the projects as per your description:

**parent-bom** - this would be having your all third party dependencies declared to maintain one version across the other projects

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent-bom</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**lib-parent** The other multi module project of the common lib as described by you.

```
|-lib-parent
| |
| |- lib-db
| |   |
| |   | - pom.xml
| | ...
| |- pom.xml
```

**lib-parent**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib-parent</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <modules>
    <module>lib-db</module>    
    <module>lib-bom</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**lib-db**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>lib-db</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

**lib-bom**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>lib-parent</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>
 <artifactId>lib-bom</artifactId>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>

 <dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
       <artifactId>lib-db</artifactId>
       <version>${project.version}</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Finally, application-parent project which will use dependencies from `parent-bom` and common lib from `lib-parent` project.

```
|- application-parent
| |
| |- module-app-db
| |  |
| |  | - pom.xml
| |  ...
| |- pom.xml
```

**application-parent**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>application-parent</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <modules>
    <module>module-app-db</module>    
  </modules>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**module-app-db**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>application-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>module-app-db</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>lib-db</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

To build above project, here are the steps:

```
$cd /path/to/parent-bom-dir && mvn clean install
$cd /path/to/lib-parent-dir && mvn clean install
$cd /path/to/application-parent-dir && mvn clean install
```

Let me know if this works with you or not.

Comment: this worked well, I know this is a new questions but imagine 'lib-db' is used by another module 'lib-domain' under ' under same parent (lib-parent) . how can it be tackled , using your proposed solution ??

Comment: I think you can directly specify it in `dependencies` section of `lib-domain` as:     `<dependency><groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId><artifactId>lib-db</artifactId><version>${project.version}</version></dependency>` 
This would be another child of the same parent, thus `bom` import might not be necessary.

Comment: thanks i thought the same , but not sure was it right way to do it or not thanks for your help. I will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'm using an answer, but if you comment I can reply.

As I remember, a BOM is created to define a custom library, with all the dependencies needed to my project(s), and it's used to keep track of the versions in one single place, so that when I update one or more dependencies I don't have to bother modifying all my projects that import them.

Now, I am asking: would it be correct in your project structure to have `projects-lib-root` shared with all the sub-projects? And in this case, would it make sense to include it within the bom-project?

What do you think?

Comment: yes projects-lib-root is shared with all projects. yes we can add it bom project . But is this an anti-pattern??  will raise issue of cyclic dependency ??

Comment: did you try to put `projects-lib-root` in the bom project? in the [maven doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) says that the dependencies should go in the `dependencyManagement` tag of the bom.

Comment: my idea was something like:
`bom-project
 + project-libs-root (in the dependencyManagement)
 + other libs
`
then `application-root` would use bom-project as parent. 

sounds reasonable?

Comment: yes , i tried that earlier . it works . But my doubt is right way ? Am i going against industry standards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements fully, I would suggest having a "parent pom" for the internal dependencies. Meaning, this pom file would have `<dependenciesManagement>` with all internal dependencies.

This parent pom will have a parent, which is another parent pom, with the 3rd-party dependencies. Other components can use this parent-pom directly, without (bypassing) the "internal" parent pom.

Hope that makes sense.